# ¿Cómo exportar mi dataframe a .txt en pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, formato, data

Tengo este *dataframe*, es un archivo `.txt` separado por espacios, el cual necesité reordenar algunas columnas con pandas:

```
I id NA19240 NA19240 NA19238 NA19238 NA19239 NA19239 
A  phenotype 0 0 0 0 0 0 
M . T T G T T T 
M . T C T C C C 
M . T C T C C C 
M . G A G A A A
```

No lo quiero en `.csv` porque me genera comas, ni tampoco en binario por que necesito leerlo. Necesito que siga estando separado por espacios para respetar el formato.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo lo exporto nuevamente a un archivo `.txt` y que conserve el formato?

¡Muchas gracias de antemano! Saludos

Comment: Disculpad, voté para cerrar incorrectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes guardar un archivo de texto que utilice el espacio como separador con el método `to_csv` del dataframe, con lo cual deja de ser formalmente un csv, pero eso ya es otra discusión.

Suponiendo que tu dataframe está en la variable `df`, prueba lo siguiente:

```
import csv

df.to_csv('datos.txt', sep=" ", 
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=" ")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias jachguate, seguí tu consejo utilizando el argumento sep=' ', funcionó muy bien, muchas gracias!
Saludos!